# How can we we give query for embedded documents through java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, document

i want to access the embedded document through java query from mongodb.from a simple document its easy but how can we access from embedded document ?

Comment: are you by any chance asking the question. How can I perform a query that extracts an embedded document and returns it ? if it's the case you can't using a query. In 2.2 you could do this using the aggregation framework but it might still be more performant to do the normal query and handle it in code.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you correctly, you can find the answer of your question below.

Say you have the following nested document.

```
{ "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : {
             "key21" : "value21",
             "key22" : "value22"
           }
}
```

If you mean to make query on the nested documents then you can access the embedded object using the following java code.

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("collectionName");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("key2.key21", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "value21"));
DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);
```

If you mean to extract embedded document from the document then you can use  [Map/Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) or [Aggregation framework.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation)

Ian Daniel is still added the code to insert nested documents that you asked. You can also visit [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-insert-a-document/) page to see some detailed examples.

Comment: What $eq doing here ? and can we insert nested document like above i tried this 
`code`

Comment: `BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
 doc.put("Name.FirstName" , new BasicDBObject("$set", nam));
 doc.put("Name.LastName" , new BasicDBObject("$set", nam1));
 coll.insert(doc):` 
 where nam and nam1 are strings which i am getting through  textfields entered by the users and contain Firstname and LastName 
 So, in the last i want to show mongDB my collection like this:
   `{ID:23
    {Name:{"FirstName": "Ahmad" 
           "SecondName":"Khan"}`
but its NOT working
I hope you understand my question

Comment: thanks for pervious code:) it works in finding but now i want to insert ? i hav given my sample code above but its not working

Comment: sorry for late response. Ian Daniel is added the code that you want.I also add a link that explains how to insert nested documents.You can read this for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The following Java code will insert a document of the form `{ID:23 {Name:{"FirstName": "Ahmad", "SecondName":"Khan"}}`

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
DBCollection people = db.getCollection("people");

BasicDBObject name = new BasicDBObject();
name.put("FirstName", "Ahmad");
name.put("LastName", "Khan");

BasicDBObject person = new BasicDBObject();
person.put("ID", 23);
person.put("Name", name);

people.insert(person);
```